# In Ruby, is it necessary to memoize a method that returns a constant value/object?

Tags: ruby, performance

Given the following method:

```
def some_hash
  {
    :one => 1,
    :two => 2,
  }
end
```

Is there any performance benefit from memoizing the hash?

```
def some_hash
  @some_hash ||= {
    :one => 1,
    :two => 2,
  }
end
```

Comment: It's not necessary if you don't mind the overhead of computing the result each time.

Comment: I didn't even know you could write methods like the first one. Since it was determined that version is so much slower, when might you want to use that version?

Comment: @theTinMan I thought the interpreter might do some optimization here, so the question really should have been, does the interpreter optimize this, or is the calculation/allocation/etc... performed over and over each time?

Comment: The interpreter does no memoization for you. That is a programmer-choice. Memoization can be counter-productive if the method being memoized gets called often, but with differing inputs, and then never called again. Memory would be consumed with no advantage to the program's execution speed. Memoization helps if the values being remembered are going to be needed many times. Your example is very simplistic; Usually we'd cache into a hash that could handle thousands of entries.

Comment: Would it be better in this example to define a constant? That's what constants are for. As for memoizing non-constant methods, I would use external cache, at least I can reset it as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the memoized variant is about 7.5 times faster:

```
def hash1
  {
    :one => 1,
    :two => 2,
  }
end

def hash2
  @some_hash ||= {
    :one => 1,
    :two => 2,
  }
end


require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bmbm do |b|
  b.report do
    1_000_000.times{ hash1 }
  end
end

Benchmark.bmbm do |b|
  b.report do
    1_000_000.times{ hash2 }
  end
end
```

```
Rehearsal ------------------------------------
   1.470000   0.030000   1.500000 (  1.499750)
--------------------------- total: 1.500000sec

       user     system      total        real
   1.570000   0.030000   1.600000 (  1.739230)
Rehearsal ------------------------------------
   0.210000   0.000000   0.210000 (  0.231601)
--------------------------- total: 0.210000sec

       user     system      total        real
   0.210000   0.010000   0.220000 (  0.234898)
```

Comment: This is because the Hash is created every time for the plain implementation, whereas it's just a variable lookup in the memoized version. So allocating and initializing a Hash takes 7.5 times as long as looking up an instance variable.

Comment: I guessed that, but i didn't dare to write something i wasnt sure about. But it makes sense.

Comment: Bummer! I was hoping that there would be some optimization by the interpreter that would account for the fact that the constant hash can't ever change since its not calculated, and there would be some caching going on in the background. Thanks!

Comment: @jakeonrails: But the hash *can* change! Ruby is not a purely functional language. It has shared state. It has mutable state. It has the worst kind of state: shared mutable state. See [my answer](http://StackOverflow.Com/a/12224293/2988/) for an example.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler / interpreter *cannot* automatically transform the first form into the second form, since the two are *not* equivalent:

```
a1, b1 = hash1, hash1
a1[:one] = 'ONE'

a2, b2 = hash2, hash2
a2[:one] = 'ONE'

p b1[:one], b2[:one]
# 1
# 'ONE'
```

Once again, shared mutable state rears its ugly head. No, kids, it's not just about concurrency!

Comment: Apart from not programming in Ruby, what approaches do you take to avoid this problem? (As you probably know, I'm not being rhetorical here - I'd genuinely like to know)